# Запуск php скрипта содержащего curl из командной строки

Tags: php, curl, командная-строка

При запуске кода php, в котором используется curl, из командной строки, не возвращаются curl запросы (просто пусто, никаких ошибок нет).
Как я понимаю, происходит так из-за того что командная строка не наделена свойствами браузера и запросам некуда возвращаться.
Но с другой стороны если я, например использую VBA (XMLHTTPObject) в excel для той же цели, то запросы возвращаются, т.е. тут не влияет - с браузера ушел запрос или нет...

Какое решение тогда должно быть? Как все-таки запустить в фоновом режиме такой скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl не имеет отношение к браузеру, думаю вы результат курла сохраняете в файл, а путь к файлу указали относительно. Попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу.